# MongoDB aggregation and sums by common field inside an array

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregate

I'm trying to get a list that counts all the victories and battles grouped by player name out of this json that I obtain from an API:

```
[
    {
        "createdDate": 1541411260,
        "players": [
            {
                "tag": "tag1234",
                "name": "name1",
                "battles": 2,
                "wins": 1
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag124567",
                "name": "name2",
                "battles": 1,
                "wins": 0
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag1234",
                "name": "name3",
                "battles": 3,
                "wins": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "createdDate": 1541411460,
        "players": [
            {
                "tag": "tag1234",
                "name": "name1",
                "battles": 1,
                "wins": 1
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag124567",
                "name": "name2",
                "battles": 1,
                "wins": 1
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag1234",
                "name": "name3",
                "battles": 0,
                "wins": 0
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag124567",
                "name": "name4",
                "battles": 1,
                "wins": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "createdDate": 1541455260,
        "players": [
            {
                "tag": "tag1234",
                "name": "name1",
                "battles": 0,
                "wins": 0
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag124567",
                "name": "name2",
                "battles": 4,
                "wins": 4
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag1234",
                "name": "name3",
                "battles": 6,
                "wins": 6
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

The mongo query I'm using is the following but I can't get the names and battles/wins:

```
db.getCollection("logs").aggregate([
    { $unwind : '$players' },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { name: '$players.name' },
            numBattles: { $sum: '$players.battles' },
            numWins: { $sum: '$players.wins' }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            name: "$_id.name",
            numBattles: '$_id.numBattles',
            numWins: '$_id.numWins',
            _id: 0
        }
]
).pretty();
```

This gave me 0 results.
Also tried the following but it's returning a full group of players and their stats:

```
db.getCollection("logs").aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { name: '$players.name' },
            numBattles: { $sum: '$players.battles' },
            numWins: { $sum: '$players.wins' }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            name: "$_id.name",
            numBattles: '$_id.numBattles',
            numWins: '$_id.numWins',
            _id: 0
        }
    }
]
).pretty();
```

The idea is to get something like this:
name1 - 3 battles and 2 wins,
name2 - x battles and y wins,
...

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `$project` stage you're referring to `_id` which contains only `name` and other fields should be referenced directly so you just need to change your `$project` to:

```
{
    $project: {
        name: "$_id.name",
        numBattles: "$numBattles",
        numWins: "$numWins",
        _id: 0
    }
}
```